# Trying to install Homebrew, but I get this "fatal: cannot create directory at 'Library/ENV/pkgconfig/10.10': Permission denied"

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am having issues with Brew. It was working fine, but now it's a little wonky.

Tried re-installing, but I get this error:"fatal: cannot create directory at 'Library/ENV/pkgconfig/10.10': Permission denied"

Anyone know how to fix this?

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
-e:70: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/Library/...
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1    
Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod g+rwx /Library/Caches/Homebrew
Password:
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
remote: Counting objects: 207213, done.    
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (55712/55712), done.    
remote: Total 207213 (delta 150324), reused 207201 (delta 150315)    
Receiving objects: 100% (207213/207213), 43.70 MiB | 3.08 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (150324/150324), done.
From https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew
* [new branch]      master     -> origin/master    
fatal: cannot create directory at 'Library/ENV/pkgconfig/10.10': Permission denied    
Failed during: git reset --hard origin/master
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest go and visit 'Library/ENV/pkgconfig/10.10', if it's there, try to look at its permission, if it differs, try to delete it and re-run the installation.

It happen to me once also but it's coming from sass/grunt. Permission denied just to find out that special file was created by other user (because I copied it from somewhere) and it have overriding problems, thats why it return permission denied.

Well, that's my case, hope this little stuff might help you. Who knows :P

Comment: Thanks man. No such file exists. I installed Homebrew in a different folder and symlinked it to /usr/local/bin, then I ran Brew doctor. It told me Xcode is not uptodate.

So I updated Xcode, and ran it again. Still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

The error appears to be your permissions are too global on `/usr/local` so it's trying to default to `/usr/local/Library`

Try changing to `755`:

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local
```

Also the user should be `root:admin` (if not already)

```
sudo chown root:admin /usr/local
```

**NOTE**: not using the -R flag here as most, if not all stuff within /usr/local belongs to current user